# Staging and Production on same or different VPS?

Tags: vps, hosting

I'm starting a web business with a designer friend.

We are trying to find the best possible way to host our websites on a VPS.

We are dividing our workflow in two parts:

- first we create a staging website, so we can both access it online and then we should move the web site on production.
- Is it ok to host both staging and production on the same VPS, or we should buy a separate VPS for production?

Comment: The question "Is it ok to host both staging and production on the same VPS?" is answered by answering the question "Is it ok if activities on staging impact production?". I don't see how we would be able to answer that one for you.

Comment: It really depends on how complex your sites are. A static html site that lives with in a directory would be fine. Anything with a cms, or dynamic content where one could affect the other, not so good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether it is OK to host both staging and production on the same VPS is entirely up to yourself. There's certainly no laws prohibiting it, but depending on your situation there may be very good reasons for not doing it.

From what you are saying, I am assuming that you will be hosting many different websites on your production setup. In my own experience, you definitely want your production server to be something you touch as little as possible. When a site is ready to go live, it is transferred there and put live. You don't want to be constantly mocking around in a shell connection or uploading stuff to your production server. Things will go wrong at some point, especially if you have a lot of different clients on it. Mistakes happen (especially when you get to the point of having a few extra employees also working on the sites), and correcting mistakes is much easier on a non-critical staging server. Especially if you end up hosting webshops and other sites where minute-to-minute data is critical. Deleting half a days worth of shop transactions from a database can be catastrophic.

In short, the small extra cost of a separate staging machine is well worth the extra flexibility and safety it buys you. Create the best system you can think of from the beginning. It will pay off in the long run.

This is all my personal opinion, but since the question is itself of subjective nature, I will give it anyway. It's not based on "hard facts" but on 10 years experience as a hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with one webserver running a vhost for production and a vhost for staging. But if you do so, you need to understand the limitations of what you are doing.

You need sufficient isolation between the two. The login used to deploy to the staging vhost must not be able to modify production in any way. If the site only contains static files, then this is not a significant limitation.

But as soon as you log in as root, you are touching production. Do you need staging for OS updates and changes to your vhost configuration? A single VPS with two vhosts won't give you staging for such updates?

If your site is more complicated and deployments to staging often involves changes to the vhost configuration, then you shouldn't be using the same VPS for both.